# token settings in angular js

Tags: angularjs, security, access-token

I have a requirement in AngularJS.

My user token expiry is set to one hour.

Whenever I submit a form , if the token is expired,

is there any way to hold the form value till I receive token from another API and the token is updated.

Comment: Please share the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Auth Interceptor Module](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth). If your API call receives a 401 status code, it will move your API call to a buffer, does the call to receive a new token and when the new token is received your initial API call will be executed with the new token.